# Using clearfix to cancel floating

Tags: html, css, css-float

During learning CSS I tried to make the exact example as you can see on the link below using **clearfix** (sorry for non-English text, but I have no other) 
http://htmlbook.ru/files/images/layout2/3-41.png
I need to make it using **float** and **clearfix** hack

My code is:
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning float</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="float.css">
</head>
    <div class="col1 clearfix"><h3>Menu</h3>
        <p>Best photo</p>
        <p>By ages</p>
        <p>Rate</p> 
        <p>By comments</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="photo">
            <p><img src="http://churchs.kiev.ua/images/stories/Hrams/Myzej/Sofia_kievsk_1.jpg" alt="" /></p>
            <p class="caption">Софийский собор</p>
        </div>
        <div class="photo clearfix">
            <p><img src="http://rybinsk.go2all.ru/imgs/92/1/85222.jpg" alt="" /></p>
            <p class="caption">Польский костёл</p>
        </div>
        <p>This text should be below photos</p>
    </div>
    <p>This text should go below the columns</p>

    <div class="footer">Подвал</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.col1 {
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.col2 {
    background-color: #A9F5F2;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}

.photo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 170px;
}

img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; 
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What's wrong with using of clearfix.

Will appreciate any answer!

Answer (score 0):

the clearfix:after 'method' is used to wrap floatting child when the container  is not in `position` `absolute` or `fixed`, `floatting` or in display:`inline-block`,`inline-table` or `table`.
In your case, the element you want to clear stands after a floatting element, you only need to `clear` them. `both`, `left` or `right`.

---

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear

---

```css
.col1 {
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.col2 {
    background-color: #A9F5F2;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}

.photo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 170px;
}

img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.clearfix {
   clear: both;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

/* add some space to clear the footer */
body {
  padding-bottom:2em;/* average height of current footer: tune it if needed */
min-width:800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col1 "><h3>Menu</h3>
        <p>Best photo</p>
        <p>By ages</p>
        <p>Rate</p> 
        <p>By comments</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="photo">
            <p><img src="http://churchs.kiev.ua/images/stories/Hrams/Myzej/Sofia_kievsk_1.jpg" alt="" /></p>
            <p class="caption">Софийский собор</p>
        </div>
        <div class="photo clearfix">
            <p><img src="http://rybinsk.go2all.ru/imgs/92/1/85222.jpg" alt="" /></p>
            <p class="caption">Польский костёл</p>
        </div>
        <p class="clearfix">This text should be below photos</p>
    </div>
    <p class="clearfix">This text should go below the columns</p>

    <div class="footer">Подвал</div>
```